# Twig Datetime passed as integer in Twig function

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, twig, twig-extension

I had made a twig function where i need to pass and id and datetime object from twig.

```
 public function _getSpecificLoginHistory($userID,  \DateTime $dateTime){
        var_dump($dateTime);
        return 'taqi';
    }
```

and from twig;

```
 {{ diary.getid|_get_Login_history_on_this_date(diary.getid, diary.getcreatedat)  }}
```

But got an error that

> IT must be an instance of DateTime, integer given,

Comment: What if you remove `\DateTime`? Is the datetime displayed?

Comment: What is `IT` and where did that come from?

Comment: Keep in mind that since you're applying a filter to a variable, the *variable* itself acts as the first argument to your callback, and later on **diary.getid** is being passed as your `dateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

AS @Artamiel Said

> the variable itself acts as the first argument to your callback,

i change the code to this and it now works.

```
 {{ diary.getid|_get_Login_history_on_this_date(diary.getcreatedat)  }}
```